# XML is not schema compliant

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

It seems to not matter how I form my XML, I'm getting the following error:

```
Schema Violation in message: Element 'message': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

The first two lines of the XSD look like this:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9 xmlns:Geek="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/7.9 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:element name="message" type="Geek:Message"/>
```

The first line of my XML looks like this:

```
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance" xmlns:v7.9="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9 xsi:type="Geek:Message" xsi:schemaLocation="v7.9 /path/to/the/schema">
```

How should the first line of the message look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix two issues:

- `xmlns:v7.9="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9` is missing terminating double quote.
- `xsi:schemaLocation` is supposed to be namespace URI - schema location pairs, not namespace prefix - schema pairs.

Specifically, change your not-well-formed `message` element from

```
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"
         xmlns:v7.9="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9 
         xsi:type="Geek:Message" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="v7.9 /path/to/the/schema">
```

to

```
<message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"
         xmlns:v7.9="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9"
         xsi:type="Geek:Message" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9 /path/to/the/schema">
```

---

**Update:** As Michael Kay points out in the comments, there's more to correct here because `message` currently isn't in a namespace and therefore `xsi:schemaLocation` won't help associated this XML with an XSD.

One fix would be to add `message` to the namespace targeted by the XSD:

```
<v7.9:message xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"
              xmlns:v7.9="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9"
              xsi:type="Geek:Message" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9 /path/to/the/schema">
```

Comment: Thank you!  Missed the double quote when typing my example - the real problem was the schemaLocation namespace URI.

Comment: But that doesn't sound like the whole answer because the `message` element is in no namespace, whereas you're loading a schema for the `urn:gtig:/stuff/gunk/v7.9` namespace

Comment: Bold text is equivalent to all-caps, and is like yelling so use it very sparingly.